# Applying different styles via the media attribute of the link element fails

Tags: html, css

I was trying to apply a different style for the website on mobiles. So I use a different CSS file and max width, but in one case it does not work. What is the matter? It's the style in the mobile-website.css that does not work. But the others in the same file work fine!

```
.miannav ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 17%;
}
```

and the Desktop style:

```
.miannav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 37%;
  }

 .miannav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  text-align: left;
  }
```

and I link the files like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="mobile-home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="desktop-home.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to load the desktop-home.css first, and then the mobile-home one, because the last style loaded takes preference.

If a mobile phone it's 600px width, it is true that it's less than 640px, but it's also true that it's less than 1024px.

Comment: But the other styles that I use in the mobile.css is working fine!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the media rule for the desktop CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:641px) and (max-width: 1024px)" href="desktop-home.css">
```